# Why does the Latin letter Z represent the Russian military in the current conflict in Ukraine?

Tags: russian-federation, armed-conflict, ukraine, military, symbols

I do NOT repeat NOT mean to provoke any sort of political discussion with this question! I am simply trying to understand how the letter Z from the Latin alphabet has taken on its current meaning in Russia which uses the Cyrillic alphabet.

I know that the Cyrillic alphabet features 12 letters from the Latin alphabet (only six of which have the same sound) but Z is not one of them. How did Z come to take on its current role as a symbol of patriotism (or support for Putin)?

I really don't know what tag to use here so forgive me if I've chosen the wrong one.

Comment: This is a good question, but not a good fit for this site. Our site is about Russian language, to which this question isn't really related. It's probably a better fit for Politics SE